# String Split String With multiple columns same separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following string

```
'06/30/2020;58044.373;.001;12/31/2020;58042.373;.003;06/30/2021;78044.373;.007'
```

I need to transform it into :

```
col 1       col 2         col 3
----        -----         -----
06/30/2020  58044.373     .001
12/31/2020  58042.373     .003
06/30/2021  78044.373     .007
```

I can use only select statmets, no cursors or SP's .

Any help please?

Comment: This is just one reason why you shouldn't store delimited data in your RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround with `STRING_SPLIT`(it is not safe):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c, value,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) % 3 AS rn,
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1) / 3 AS grp
  FROM t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c, ';')
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) AS col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN value END) AS col3
FROM cte
GROUP BY c,grp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f8eeede6d137d924c0c79f02ec66eb3)**

Comment: I never feel safe trusting `STRING_SPLIT` for stuff like this. The omission of the ordinal position is a huge oversight by Microsoft.

Comment: @Larnu Totally agree, `WITH ordinality` is a must-  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896627-string-split-add-option-to-return-row-number

Comment: There's been a few of those topics since `STRING_SPLIT` was added back in 2016. I know I've voted up a couple at least.

Comment: @Larnu At least this one will be implemented one day `Thanks for the suggestion. This is in our backlog but we cannot confirm when it will be implemented.` :)

Comment: Haha, yep, probably in SQL Server 2029 ;).

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try to split the input string using JSON built-in support. You need to transform the input text into a valid JSON array and parse this JSON array with `OPENJSON()` with default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and in case of JSON array the `key` column holds the index of the element in the specified array.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'06/30/2020;58044.373;.001;12/31/2020;58042.373;.003;06/30/2021;78044.373;.007'

SELECT 
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 0 THEN [value] END) AS Col1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 1 THEN [value] END) AS Col2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 2 THEN [value] END) AS Col3
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(@json, N';', N'","'), N'"]'))
GROUP BY (CONVERT(int, [key]) / 3)
```

Result:

```
----------------------------
Col1        Col2        Col3
----------------------------
06/30/2020  58044.373   .001
12/31/2020  58042.373   .003
06/30/2021  78044.373   .007
```